# How to use jQuery in Coffeescript Interactive (REPL)?

Tags: coffeescript

So I've done...

`npm install -g jquery`

and I run `coffee` in terminal...

then I type in `require 'jquery'`

And I get an error :/. I've tried variations of the above to no avail.

How can I use jQuery functions in my Coffeescript REPL ?

Comment: What kind of error? I try `npm i coffee-script jquery` and it's work.

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup yup, it was a local vs. global jquery issue (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed a `jquery` module as global module.

### Loading local modules

If the module identifier passed to `require()` is not a native module (e.g. `http`), and does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then `Node.js` starts at the parent directory of the current module, and adds `/node_modules`, and attempts to load the module from that location.

If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and so on, until the root of the file system is reached.

### Loading global modules

To make global modules available to the Node.js (and CoffeeScript) REPL, it might be useful to also add the `/usr/lib/node_modules` folder to the `$NODE_PATH` environment variable. Since the module lookups using node_modules folders are all relative, and based on the real path of the files making the calls to `require()`, the packages themselves can be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the quirk was that I had jquery installed in the global dependency folder (i.e. the `-g` flag in `npm install -g jquery`).

Doing a simple `npm install jquery` does the trick and gets everything to work :).